# How to find all paths in a graph that start with some initial partial path?

Tags: java, jgrapht

There is the following part of the code:

```
SimpleDirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> multigraph = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
multigraph.addVertex("a");
multigraph.addVertex("b");
multigraph.addVertex("c");
multigraph.addVertex("1");
multigraph.addEdge("a", "b");
multigraph.addEdge("b", "c");
multigraph.addEdge("c", "1");
```

Dependencies:

```
gradle: implementation group: 'org.jgrapht', name: 'jgrapht-core', version: '1.5.1'
```

I also have only a part of the path ("abc"). And I need to get on this part all possible paths that include this part, that is, in this case: "abc1".

[image: graph]

**How can i do this?** AsSubgraph, AllDirectedPaths, GraphWalk, BFSShortestPath - this all does not give the desired result, it just outputs the part that I know.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish. What is a 'part' or a 'piece'? Also, in your graph, what is a 'branch'? A branch in graph theory typically refers to a tree graph rooted in some vertex. Do you simply want to find a path from vertex A to 1? Best to revise your question and clarify. Also did you deliberately pick a pseudograph instead of a simple directed graph?

Comment: @JorisKinable In this case, the type of the graph does not matter. Yes, I just want to find a path from vertex A to 1 along the known edges A-> B, B-> C. I don't know how to get all possible elements after C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are looking to find all paths in a graph that start with some initial partial path `p1=[v_1,v_2,...,v_n]`. To do so, we must find every path `p2` that starts at vertex `v_n` (the last vertex of `p1`) and ends in some other vertex not yet visited by `p1`.
There are two alternative ways to accomplish this:

1. Run a shortest path algorithm from vertex v_n in a graph that does not contain any of the vertices in `p1` except `v_n`.
2. Run a BFS from vertex `v_n` in a graph that does not contain any of the vertices in `p1` except `v_n`.

Both solutions in code:

```
public static void shortestPathSolution(){
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph=getGraph();

    List<String> partialPathP1=List.of("a","b","c"); //some partial path
    String source=partialPathP1.get(partialPathP1.size()-1); //the last vertex of P1
    List<List<String>> completePaths = new ArrayList<>();

    //To prevent P2 from revisiting vertices in P1, create a graph which hides all but the last vertex in P1.
    Set<String> vertexSubset=new HashSet<>(graph.vertexSet());
    vertexSubset.removeAll(partialPathP1);
    vertexSubset.add(source);
    Graph<String,DefaultEdge> inducedSubgraph = new AsSubgraph<>(graph, vertexSubset);

    //Find the shortest paths from the end of P1 to all reachable vertices in the graph
    ShortestPathAlgorithm.SingleSourcePaths<String,DefaultEdge> shortestPaths=new DijkstraShortestPath<>(inducedSubgraph).getPaths(source);
    //Iterate over the reachable vertices and construct all extensions
    for(String vertex : inducedSubgraph.vertexSet()){
        if(vertex.equals(source)) continue;
        GraphPath<String, DefaultEdge> gp = shortestPaths.getPath(vertex);
        if(gp == null) continue; //No path exists from the end of P1 to the given vertex

        //Obtain path P2
        List<String> partialPathP2 = gp.getVertexList();
        //Construct path P by concatenating P1 and P2
        List<String> pathP = new ArrayList<>(partialPathP1);
        pathP.addAll(partialPathP2.subList(1, partialPathP2.size()));
        completePaths.add(pathP);
    }

    System.out.println(completePaths);
}

public static void bfsSolution(){
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = getGraph();

    List<String> partialPathP1 = List.of("a", "b", "c"); //some partial path
    String source = partialPathP1.get(partialPathP1.size() - 1); //the last vertex of P1
    List<List<String>> completePaths = new ArrayList<>();

    //To prevent P2 from revisiting vertices in P1, create a graph which hides all but the last vertex in P1.
    Set<String> vertexSubset = new HashSet<>(graph.vertexSet());
    vertexSubset.removeAll(partialPathP1);
    vertexSubset.add(source);
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> inducedSubgraph = new AsSubgraph<>(graph, vertexSubset);

    //Run a BFS from the source vertex. Each time a new vertex is encountered, construct a new path.
    BreadthFirstIterator<String, DefaultEdge> bfs = new BreadthFirstIterator<>(inducedSubgraph, source);
    while(bfs.hasNext()){
        String vertex=bfs.next();
        //Create path P2 that ends in the vertex by backtracking from the new vertex we encountered
        Stack<String> partialPathP2 = new Stack<>();
        while(vertex != null) {
            partialPathP2.push(vertex);
            vertex=bfs.getParent(vertex);
        }
        partialPathP2.pop(); //Remove the source vertex
        List<String> pathP = new ArrayList<>(partialPathP1.size()+partialPathP2.size());
        pathP.addAll(partialPathP1);
        while(!partialPathP2.isEmpty())
            pathP.add(partialPathP2.pop());
        completePaths.add(pathP);
    }

    System.out.println(completePaths);
}

public static Graph<String,DefaultEdge> getGraph(){
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = new SimpleDirectedGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
    Graphs.addAllVertices(graph, List.of("a","b","c","1","2","3"));
    graph.addEdge("a", "b");
    graph.addEdge("b", "c");
    graph.addEdge("c", "1");
    graph.addEdge("c", "2");
    graph.addEdge("1", "3");
    graph.addEdge("2", "3");
    return graph;
}
```

Result:

```
[[a, b, c], [a, b, c, 1], [a, b, c, 2], [a, b, c, 1, 3]]
```

Note:
For performance reasons, it is always best to choose the graph type that best suits your application. If you don't need self-loops and multiple edges, instead of choosing a `DirectedPseudograph`, it would be better to use a `SimpleDirectedGraph`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I don't know target vertex and I have to understand all possible endpoints along the path (a, b, c).

Comment: @МишаковАлександр this is completely unclear from your original question. At the very least you want to provide a proper example that clearly explains your problem, the input and the desired output. Provide a [MWE ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be very helpful if your graphical example is a little more elaborate, showing different paths and the desired output.

Comment: @МишаковАлександр I've updated the answer. I hope this is what you intended to do. Either way, you'd still have to update your question such that anyone else who finds your question can also understand it and benefit from the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for!